# Mensagem de erro ao adicionar dados no formulário gerado no framework Phreeze

Tags: php, json, framework, xampp

Em todas as aplicações geradas utilizando o *framework PHP Phreeze* em ambiente local (Xampp), ao adicionar um registro através do formulário, que também foi gerado, obtêm-se a seguinte mensagem de erro para o usuário:

> An unknown error occured

Abaixo o arquivo 'app.js' localizado na pasta 'scripts', também gerado pelo *Phreeze*:

```
getErrorMessage: function(resp) {
var msg = 'An unknown error occured';
    try
    {
        var json = $.parseJSON(resp.responseText);
        msg = json.message;
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        // TODO: possibly use regex or some other more robust way to get details...?
        var parts = resp.responseText.split(app.errorLandmarkStart);

        if (parts.length > 1)
        {
            var parts2 = parts[1].split(app.errorLandmarkEnd);
            msg = parts2[0]
        }
    }

    return msg ? msg : 'Unknown server error';
},
```

Depois de atualizar a página, verifica-se que o *insert* no banco foi executado com sucesso, porém não fica visível no lado cliente da aplicação, parece ocorrer algum problema por parte do `JSON`, ou em alguma parte da camada *view*.

Alguém já passou por este mesmo problema? Apenas ratificando o problema é somente no lado cliente da aplicação, já que os dados são inseridos normalmente no banco.

Comment: Talvez seja "somente no lado cliente". Você precisa ver como o `PHP` está respondendo. De onde está vindo essa mensagem de erro? Do console do navegador?

Comment: getErrorMessage: function(resp) {

  var msg = 'An unknown error occured';
  try
  {
   var json = $.parseJSON(resp.responseText);
   msg = json.message;
  }
  catch (error)
  {
   // TODO: possibly use regex or some other more robust way to get details...?
   var parts = resp.responseText.split(app.errorLandmarkStart);

   if (parts.length > 1)
   {
    var parts2 = parts[1].split(app.errorLandmarkEnd);
    msg = parts2[0]
   }
  }

  return msg ? msg : 'Unknown server error';
 },

Comment: Ponha o código na pergunta, fica mais legível. Mas creio que meu palpite está certo: é algo com a resposta do `PHP`. OU está vindo errada OU o `JavaScript` não está interpretando direito.

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?

Comment: Atualiza os scripts backbone-min.js e underscore-min.js em sua pasta de scripts que irá funcionar!

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Resolvido.